# Stabilizer action on subspace lattice

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, reference-request

Let $F$ denote a finite field, and let $V$ denote a vector space over $F$. Let $P$ denote the poset of subspaces of $V$, where the partial order is defined by inclusion. Fix $u \in P$. Denote by $\mathrm{Stab}(u)$ the subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}(V)$ that stabilizes $u$. Then for two subspaces $v, w \in P$ the following are equivalent:

1. Elements $v$, $w$ belong to the same orbit of $\mathrm{Stab}(u)$-action on $P$.
2. $\dim v = \dim w$ and $\dim (u \cap v) = \dim (u \cap w)$.

I was going to prove this from scratch, but my advisor wants me to find a citation for this, since it’s a very well-known fact apparently. Could anyone locate me to the paper which states this, or a theorem that has this fact as a corollary? Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The condition that $F$ is a finite field is superfluous and the reference to partial order on $P$ is also superfluous. Your statement is a trivial consequence of the theorems about bases and existence of linear transformations. However, it is an excellent exercise for first-year students of linear algebra.

Comment: @kabenyuk do papers just say them like a basic fact if they are to use this proposition?

Comment: The proof of the statement $2\Rightarrow1$ that I mean uses only the following facts from the basics of linear algebra: 
Every linearly independent system can be augmented to a basis and a linear transformation is uniquely defined if the images of the basis vectors are given.
The statement $1\Rightarrow2$ follows from the equality $(u\cap w)^g=u^g\cap v^g$.